# How do I create a data frame with multiples random generated colums?

Tags: python

I generated a data frame with 100 rows like below:

```
    df = []
    D=100
    for n in range(100):
        D = D*(random.uniform(0.9,1.1))
        df.append(D)

df=pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Now I want to create a Data Frame with 50 columns generated like this. Is there some kind of .append for creating columns? I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Just look up how to create a dataframe with random data.  `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))` the first link that I googled had this.

Comment: I was hoping for a way where I dont need to name every column.

Comment: Do you need to?  I think you can set it wo names.  Also why not just use a numpy array at that point.